# How access variable from url string using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have htaccess like this

```
RewriteRule i_am_(.*)_fan([0-9]).html$ /fans.php?player=$1&page=$2
```

When i enter url like this `http://messi_fans.com/i_am_messi_fan2.html`.it redirect to the page http://messi_fans.com/fans.php. But the **GET** variable is

```
Array ( [player] => messi_fan2 [page] => )
```

I want **GET** like this  `Array ( [player] => messi [page] =>2 )` 
How to modify above htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Start by using at least the basic directives and some condition to prevent a loop, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !fans\.php                        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/i_am_([^_]+)_fan([^.]+)\.html/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*              fans.php?player=%1&page=%2        [L]
```

Map silently

`http://messi_fans.com/i_am_messi_fan2.html`  with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://messi_fans.com/fans.php?player=messi&page=2`

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) by appending a question mark to your `.*`:

```
i_am_(.*?)_fan([0-9]).html$
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
RewriteRule i_am_([a-zA-Z])_fan([0-9]).html$ /fans.php?player=$1&page=$2
```